# Packaging a Handlebars-based widget: javascript and html

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm relatively new to this, so please excuse if I'm missing some obvious point...

I'd like to create a reusable widget using Handlebars, for simplicity let's consider a Users table:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="temp1">
       <table>
         {{#users}} 
            <tr><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{email}}</td></tr> 
         {{/users}} 
       </table>
</script>

<script>
   var template=Handlebars.compile($("#temp1").html());    
   function renderUsersTable(users, divId){
       $("#"+divId).html(template(users:users));
   }
<script>
```

This works, but I only got it to work with the template script (text/x-handlebars-template)  **embedded into my business page**. That's not reusable: if I need it on another page, I'll need to copy-paste. I considered quoting the template into a javascript string variable, but that's ugly especially since my real html is pretty large.

Are there any better practices, that allow to separate the handlebars template into a dedicated file, to be included into different pages as needed?

Thanks very much

Comment: you can use Handlebars' **Partial** feature

Comment: thanks, that's not exactly what I was shooting for *but* this Partial is an excellent feature I wasn't aware of, so thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. One way is to use a `gulp` task to compile all your templates. The example below takes all the individual handlebars files from a directory and puts them in one javascript file `hb_templates.js` as templates. Each template is given the name of the file it came from. For your example you could put your template into `users.handlebars`. Then include the generated `hb_templates.js` after `Handlebars.js` in your production webpage.

```
gulp.task('handlebars', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/views/*.handlebars')
  .pipe(htmlmin({
    collapseWhitespace: true
  }))
  .pipe(handlebars())
  .pipe(wrap(function(data) {
    var filename = data.file.history[0].split('\\').pop().split('.')[0];
    return "Handlebars.templates." + filename + "=Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)";
  }))
  .pipe(concat('hb_templates.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/scripts/'));
});
```

You use the template like this;

```
$("#"+divId).html(Handlebars.templates.user(users:users));
```

Since partials in `Handlebars` are just templates you can use these templates inside other template files like so

```
<div>
{{> user}}
</div>
```

Just register them as partials once you have loaded `hb_templates.js` like this;

```
handlebars.registerPartial('user', handlebars.templates.user);
```

The example used the following dependencies in `nodejs` for `gulp`

```
{
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-handlebars": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "1.1.3",
    "gulp-wrap": "0.11.0",
    "handlebars": "3.0.3",
}
```

Comment: No problem. Added an edit to show how to use the same templates as partials.